# Proper way to get meta of my Pebble app with Pebble iOS Kit

Tags: c, pebble-watch

I know how to get the meta information about firmware, but what is the proper way to get meta from appinfo.json of my Pebble app with Pebble iOS Kit? (i.e. versionLabel)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. Pebble plans to add an API to do that in the future.